# Segmentation fault shown by debugger. Unable to locate the fault

Tags: c, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int x)
{
     if(x<=20)
     {
     printf("d\n",x);
     return fun(2*x);
     return fun(x/2);
     }
 }
main()
{
      int x;
      printf("Enter the number\n");
      scanf("%d",x);
      fun(x);
}
```

Comment: Implicit `int`? Two returns in one method?

Answer (score 3):

That should be `scanf("%d", &x);`, and probably `printf("%d\n", x);`.

Also, you're returning something (*twice*!) from a `void` function. Your code will not work as it is.

Comment: +1. GCC compiles it. Of course, with `-Wall` it (rightly) complains.

Comment: @Billy, I guess it just drops the return value. It would be fun if it optimized out the function call because its result is never used, though. Thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 1):

in the function if you are planning to print the value of x it should be printf("%d\n",x);
you are missing % symbol.also the second return statement in your function will never be executed..

Comment: While true, that's not what's causing the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

On top of what other folks said, after you fix all other programmatic mistakes  you are directing your program to an infinite recursion.

Comment: Write a function Compute(int x) such that it prints the values of x, 2x, 4x, 8x …. till the value doesn’t exceed 20000. After reaching 20000, it again comes back from …8x, 4x, 2x, x and stops there.
Note: (1) You can’t use any local variables in the function
(2) You can’t use any loops (for or while or do..while) or any GOTO statement.

Comment: I suggest you add the 'homework' tag to your question, and please edit it and put the actual question there. Otherwise people will vote your question down and it will affect your future reputation in the website.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fun(int x)
{    
     if(x<=20000)
     {
     printf("%d\n",x);
      fun(x<<1);     
     printf("%d\n",x);
     }   
 }
main()
{
      int x;
      printf("Enter the number\n");
      scanf("%d",&x);
      printf("\n");
      fun(x);
      system("pause");
}
```

This is the correct program, I was looking for. Thank u all!

Comment: Please use the { } button to properly format a block of code when you post it.